# Proving the range $R$ and null space $N$ of a linear operator are independent iff $V = R \oplus N$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Let $R$ be the range of $T$ and let $N$ be the null space of $T$. Prove that $R$ and $N$ are independent if and only if $V= R \oplus N$.

Theorems that can be used:

> Let $T \in L(V,V), W_{1} , \ldots, W_{k}$ be subspaces of $V$, and $ E_{1} , ..., E_{k}$ be projections on $V$ such that:
>
> (i) $E_{i} E_{j} = 0$ if $i \neq j$
>
> (ii) $E_{1} + \cdots + E_{k} =I$
>
> (iii) $ImE_{i} = W_{i}$  $(1 \leq i \leq k)$
>
> Then each $W_{i}$ is $T$-invariant iff $T$ commutes with each $E_{i}$

Comment: What does the second part of your question have to do with the first? Are there two questions?

Comment: This problem is in Hoffman's/Kunz's, "$Linear~Algebra$," 2nd ed., in fact (see page 218). The theorem (not theorems) stated above is Theorem 11 within the section this question is an exercise of (section 6.7). I came here to see if this could be proven another way; however, I proved the "$\Rightarrow$" direction by Dennis' answer below. Lastly, the "$\Leftarrow$" direction is trivial, using Hoffman's/Kunz's definition of the direct sum of subspaces (namely, the only lemma in section 6.6). The above theorem is simply a theorem in section 6.7, which isn't needed using Dennis' answer below.

Comment: I mainly commented since I wanted to implicate that the "$\Leftarrow$" direction in the proof is trivial by the definition in the book I reference above.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question: use the theorem on dimensions:
$$\dim V=\dim\ker(T)+\dim\operatorname{im}(T)$$
Do you know the definition of two spaces to be independent? If so, you should be able to finish from here.